# Integrating ActiveMQ with Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, activemq-classic

I am looking for tips on integrating activemq with tomcat.

My architecture looks like below where each app is running on a different jvm/machines,

producer app -> tomcat (activemq) -> consumer app

The consumers and producers should connect to activemq on a remote machine. I would also like to have the web console enabled.

Comment: Easiest approach: 1) Download Apache [TomEE](http://activemq.apache.org/tomcat.html) (a Tomcat which comes pre-integrated with ActiveMQ), 2) Start coding your app :)

Comment: @paulsm4 - I dont want to use TomEE.

Comment: Q: If not, why not?  Q: At the same link, did you see the information for setting up ActiveMQ manually?  Did it answer your question(s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should download and install ActiveMQ on remote machine, web console will be enabled by default.

Second you should configure each tomcat node.

Put activemq-all.jar (version 5.11 and higher, you can download here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-all) into ***$TOMCAT_HOME/lib*** folder.
ActiveMQ has ready JNDI resource factory for all its administered objects: ConnectionFactory and destinations.
You must provide it as a parameter factory for your resources:

Add to ***$TOMCAT_HOME/CONF/context.xml***

```
<Resource name="jms/activemq-factory" 
        auth="Container" 
        type="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" 
        description="JMS Connection Factory" 
        factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory" 
        brokerURL="tcp://${broker.host}:${broker.port}" 
        brokerName="LocalActiveMQBroker" 
        useEmbeddedBroker="false"/>

<Resource name="jms/activemq-topic" 
            auth="Container" 
            type="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic" 
            factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory" 
            physicalName="activemq-topic"/>
```

replace broker.host and broker.port to real ActiveMQ parameters.

Now you can write consumers for acticvemq-topic. 
Thats all.

Comment: I've tried your solution here but I'm not seeing the broker port being listened on when I check netstat on a linux server. I'm using Tomcat 8 and Java 8 and I'm not sure if that is the issue?